# SQL - i want select - and update selected

Tags: mysql, sql

I need little help, I have this SQL select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'gknwcrpostmeta' 
WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_fgd2wp_old_node_id' 
  AND 'meta_value' IN ( SELECT 'object_id' 
                        FROM 'gknwcrterm_relationships' 
                        WHERE 'object_id' = 'meta_value')
```

It's working OK.

Now I want to update - what select found so I write this query:

```
UPDATE 'gknwcrpostmeta'
SET 'meta_key' = 'sac_locked', 'meta_value' = 'logged in'
FROM 'gknwcrpostmeta' 
WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_fgd2wp_old_node_id' 
  AND 'meta_value' IN ( SELECT 'object_id' 
                        FROM 'gknwcrterm_relationships' 
                        WHERE 'object_id' = 'meta_value')
```

simulation query goes OK, but real query return:

> #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'FROM 'gknwcrpostmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_fgd2wp_old_node_id' AND 'meta_valu' on line 3

Any advice?

Comment: You are using single quote where none are needed.  I am voting to close as a simply typographical error.

Comment: The first query is already invalid SQL. I am surprised that it's working at all.

Comment: so any advice? also tryied with no quote

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in my database. I just replaced the table name with yours.

```
UPDATE EmploymentAssignment
SET approver = 1
FROM  EmploymentAssignment ea INNER JOIN ( SELECT personID , schoolID FROM EmploymentAssignment WHERE personID LIKE '%75' AND schoolID IN ( 2,3,4) ) t on ea.personID = t.personID AND ea.schoolID = t.schoolID
```

so translate to yours it would look like:

```
UPDATE `gknwcrpostmeta`
SET `meta_key` = 'sac_locked', `meta_value` = 'logged in'
FROM `gknwcrpostmeta` a INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `gknwcrpostmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_fgd2wp_old_node_id' AND `meta_value` IN ( SELECT `object_id` FROM `gknwcrterm_relationships` WHERE `object_id` = `meta_value`)) t on a.`meta_key` = t.`meta_key` AND a.`meta_value` = t.`meta_value`
```

hope this helps

Comment: thanky you, but still no working:
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'FROM `gknwcrpostmeta` a INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `gknwcrpostmeta` WHERE `meta_k' on line 3

Comment: Can you post the result of your first query?

Comment: I removed that quotes so this is FIRST query:
`code`
SELECT * FROM gknwcrpostmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE "_fgd2wp_old_node_id" AND meta_value IN ( SELECT object_id FROM gknwcrterm_relationships WHERE object_id = meta_value)

result is:
`code`
17  3  _fgd2wp_old_node_id  6
20  4  _fgd2wp_old_node_id  7 
23  5  _fgd2wp_old_node_id  8
26  6  _fgd2wp_old_node_id  9

...

Comment: @Boris Berčík Please put your sql code between backtick symbol (`) so it is readable

Comment: `SELECT * FROM gknwcrpostmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE "_fgd2wp_old_node_id" AND meta_value IN ( SELECT object_id FROM gknwcrterm_relationships WHERE object_id = meta_value) `

Comment: `17  3  _fgd2wp_old_node_id  6`

this is result example @O.KOO

Comment: Thanks. Can you please also post how your current second query looks like? the one that is giving the error?

Comment: `UPDATE gknwcrpostmeta 
SET meta_key = 'sac_locked',
    meta_value = 'logged in'
FROM gknwcrpostmeta
WHERE
meta_key = '_fgd2wp_old_node_id' 
AND
meta_value 
IN (SELECT object_id FROM gknwcrterm_relationships);`

Comment: this is code that what im trying non. but I also tryied your code with same no-working result. @O.KOO

Comment: Can you try to incorporate the `INNER JOIN` I used in my query into yours? Also, do you get the same error from both your old and current query?

Comment: finaly this code working: `UPDATE gknwcrpostmeta SET meta_key = 'sac_locked', meta_value = 'logged in' WHERE meta_key = '_fgd2wp_old_node_id' AND meta_value IN(SELECT object_id FROM gknwcrterm_relationships)` thank you for assistance

Comment: Congrats! I am just curious if my solution would have work or not? Can you try this code and see if it works?
`UPDATE gknwcrpostmeta
SET meta_key = 'sac_locked', meta_value = 'logged in' 
FROM gknwcrpostmeta a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM gknwcrpostmeta WHERE meta_key = '_fgd2wp_old_node_id' AND meta_value IN (SELECT object_id FROM gknwcrterm_relationships)) t ON a.meta_key  = t.meta_key  AND a.meta_value = b.meta_value`

Comment: im sorry still that same error
`UPDATE gknwcrpostmeta SET meta_key = 'sac_locked', meta_value = 'logged in' FROM gknwcrpostmeta a INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM gknwcrpostmeta WHERE meta_key = '_fgd2wp_old_node_id' AND meta_value IN (SELECT object_id FROM gknwcrterm_relationships)) t ON a.meta_key = t.meta_key AND a.meta_value = b.meta_value`

`MySQL hlási: Dokumentácia
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'FROM gknwcrpostmeta a INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM gknwcrpostmeta WHERE meta_key = '  on line 1`